# Functions change values in list even though list is not passed to functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search, water-jug-problem

I'm trying to implement a I.A. breadth-first-search-like algorithm to solve the Water Jugs problem but I encountered this problem:

Every time I add a new element to the array, it changes all elements inside the array to be like it.

In other words...

The "frontier" array is changing all elements inside it between each "jug" functions calls.

Could someone share some insight about this code?

(I was more worried about implementing the logic, so it isn't optimized)

The code:

```
J1SIZE = 3
J2SIZE = 4

frontier = []
explored = []


def IsEmpty(array):
    result = False
    if len(array) == 0:
        result = True
    return result


#Fill up a jug
def fillJug(tempNode, jug):
    copyNode = tempNode
    copyNode = copyNode
    if jug == 1:
        copyNode[0] = J1SIZE
    elif jug == 2:
        copyNode[1] = J2SIZE
    print(copyNode)
    return copyNode

#Empty a jug
def emptyJug(tempNode, jug):
    copyNode = tempNode
    if jug == 1:
        copyNode[0] = 0
    elif jug == 2:
        copyNode[1] = 0
    print(copyNode)
    return copyNode

#Pass the content of a jug to another
def passJug(tempNode, jug):
    copyNode = tempNode
    if jug == 1:
        copyNode[1] = copyNode.j1
        copyNode[0] = 0
        if copyNode[1] > J2SIZE:
            copyNode[1] = J2SIZE
    elif jug == 2:
        copyNode[0] = copyNode[1]
        copyNode[1] = 0
        if copyNode[0] > J1SIZE:
            copyNode[0] = J1SIZE
    print(copyNode)
    return copyNode

#Check if solution was found
def goalTest(goalNode,currentNode):
    result = False
    if goalNode == currentNode:
        result = True
    return result

def BFS(start,end,frontier,explored):

    start_node = start
    frontier = [start_node] + frontier

    if goalTest(end,(frontier[0])):
        print('Solution:', frontier[0])
        exit()

    #Loop start
    while IsEmpty(frontier) == False:

        tempNode = frontier.pop(0)

        #Generate nodes (states)
        if tempNode[0] < J1SIZE:
            newNode = fillJug(tempNode, 1)
            if newNode not in explored:
                frontier = [newNode] + frontier
                print('Frontier1: ', frontier)

        if tempNode[1] < J2SIZE:
            newNode = fillJug(tempNode, 2)
            if newNode not in explored:
                frontier = [newNode] + frontier
                print('Frontier2: ', frontier)

        if tempNode[0] == J1SIZE:
            newNode = emptyJug(tempNode, 1)
            if newNode not in explored:
                frontier = [newNode] + frontier
                print('Frontier3: ', frontier)

        if tempNode[1] == J2SIZE:
            newNode = emptyJug(tempNode, 2)
            if newNode not in explored:
                frontier = [newNode] + frontier
                print('Frontier4: ', frontier)

        if (tempNode[0] > 0) and (tempNode[1] < J2SIZE):
            newNode = passJug(tempNode, 1)
            if newNode not in explored:
                frontier = [newNode] + frontier
                print('Frontier5: ', frontier)

        if (tempNode[1] > 0) and (tempNode[0] < J1SIZE):
            new_node = passJug(tempNode, 2)
            if new_node not in explored:
                frontier = [new_node] + frontier
                print('Frontier6: ', frontier)

        print('Frontier: ', frontier)
        print('Explored: ', explored)

        for node in frontier:
            if goalTest(end, node):
                print('Solution:', frontier[0])
                exit()
            if node not in explored:
                explored = [node] + explored

BFS([0,0],[0,2],frontier,explored)
```

The fixed code:

http://codepaste.net/auun4u

Comment: Is “Everytime I add a new element to the array, It changes all elements inside the array to be like it.” the description of your problem? It's not what is called a syntax problem.

Comment: Thanks, for the feedback!

I'll try to be more clear:

The "frontier" array is changing all elements inside it between each "jug" functions calls.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing your question a little. A “syntax error” is when the compiler tells you “missing ‘;’ on line 33”. Some people ask on StackOverflow what to do when these happen. Your question is apparently **not** a syntax error, but I am afraid that calling it so will lead people to misunderstand your question, and perhaps close it as unclear or lacking effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a smaller code example that reproduces your error:

```
J1SIZE = 3
J2SIZE = 4


def fillJug(tempNode, jug):
    copyNode = tempNode
    copyNode = copyNode
    if jug == 1:
        copyNode[0] = J1SIZE
    elif jug == 2:
        copyNode[1] = J2SIZE
    return copyNode


frontier = [[0, 0]]
tempNode = frontier.pop(0)

newNode = fillJug(tempNode, 1)
frontier = [newNode] + frontier  # (1)

newNode = fillJug(tempNode, 2)  # (2)
frontier = [newNode] + frontier
```

The problem is that in the line I've marked `(1)`, you are setting `newNode`, which refers to the same object as `tempNode` to be the first item in `frontier`.  Then, in the line I've marked `(2)`, you are changing `tempNode` -- inside `fillJug`.  So the value in `frontier` changes.  Specifically, you are having `copyNode` refer to the same object as `tempNode`, and then you are changing the data to which `copyNode` (and `tempNode`) refer.

You should redefine `copyNode` as

`copyNode = tempNode[:]`

This will cause `copyNode` and `tempNode` to refer to different objects in memory (with the same values).  (Another option is to set `copyNode` to `copy.copy(tempNode)`, after importing [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html).)

So the new `fillJug` would be

```
def fillJug(tempNode, jug):
    copyNode = tempNode[:]
    if jug == 1:
        copyNode[0] = J1SIZE
    elif jug == 2:
        copyNode[1] = J2SIZE
    return copyNode
```

The same fix applies to the other `Jug` functions.

Comment: Thank you for the attention and all information!
It worked softly! 
Now I'll focus in fix the logic according to the book!

;D